# Why shear stress vector must be parallel to flow in this example?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, atmospheric-science, navier-stokes

In the book by *S. Pal Arya "Introduction to Micrometeorology"* there is a chapter about Laminar Ekman Layers.
I refer to the following example:

[image]

Variables are:

- U, V wind velocity in x, y direction
- G Geostrophic wind magnitude
- Ug, Vg geostrophic wind in x, y
- f Coriolis Parameter
- $h_s$ a reference height at which Us is given (Vs is zero)
- K effective viscosity

The boundary condition is in particular:

[image]

In a subsequent consideration, they state, that at $z=h_s$ we need to have the following:

[image]

Why this is the case? Why must shear stress be parallel to the wind? I understand the mathematical condition derived from the statement, but why must stress in y-direction be zero? There could be a shear of v along z and this would give rise to non vanishing $\tau_{zy}$, even when $v(z)=0$ - so in general this is not the case!

Comment: Please edit your question to define all variables mentioned.

Comment: I added the description of variables